# how would i link my twitter acount to these notifications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

ok so i want to try and link my twitter account up with these notifications so that very time i post a tweet that on my website this notification automatically updates and sends a notification to my website users saying exactly what i said in the tweet how can i accomplish this? by the way when i say notification i mean as in a live update to my website!:

this is the notifications:

http://www.thorbis.com/test/

and this is my twitter widget:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Thorbis" data-widget-id="325004213753085953">Tweets by @Thorbis</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

is there an efficient way to do this properly?

Comment: a `notification`, like an email?

Comment: no as in a live update to my website! @Karl Anderson